# MySQL optimization problems with LIMIT keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a MySQL query.  The below query runs great as long as there are greater than 15 entries in the database for a particular user.

```
SELECT activityType, activityClass, startDate, endDate, activityNum, count(*) AS activityType
FROM (
   SELECT activityType, activityClass, startDate, endDate, activityNum
   FROM ActivityX
   WHERE user=? 
   ORDER BY activityNum DESC
   LIMIT 15) temp
WHERE startDate=? OR endDate=?
GROUP BY activityType
```

When there are less than 15 entries, the performance is terrible.  My timing is roughly 25 ms vs. 4000 ms.  (I need "15" to ensure I get all the relevant data.)

I found these interesting sentences:
"LIMIT  N" is the keyword and N is any number starting from 0, putting 0 as the limit does not return any records in the query. Putting a number say 5 will return five records. If the records in the specified table are less than N, then all the records from the queried table are returned in the result set.  [source: guru99.com]

To get around this problem, I'm using a heuristic to guess if the number of entries for a user is small - if so, I use a different query that takes about 1500 ms.

Is there anything I'm missing here?  I can not use an index since the data is encrypted.

Thanks much,

- Jon

Comment: You can move `WHERE startDate=? OR endDate=?` to inner select query. This would optimize the query further.

Comment: For more inside we need query plan.else it is guessing.

Comment: Thanks Madhur for the suggestion but that actually performs worse :-(  I'm guessing it has to do with the startDate and endDate constraints operating on a larger dataset in your query versus operating on a smaller dataset in my version.  But definitely a good thought.

Comment: Nebi - Since a user can use my app on multiple devices, I use this query as "reload" to ensure the current device has the latest data.  That is, for a given user, pull out of the database what they've done today.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think an index on `ActivityX(user, ActivityNum)` will solve your problem.

I am guessing that you have an index on `(ActivityNum)` and the optimizer is trying to figure out if it should use the index.  This causes thresholding.  The composite index should better match the query.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I can't use an index since the data is encrypted.  But thanks!